# Is there still not a simpler way to capture PRIOR value of a field in Email templates?

Tags: email-template

I need to capture the OLD/Current value of few fields in Email template. I found many posts related to it saying to create a new custom field to capture **OLD** value via workflow rule and then use this field in the template.

Wanted to know if in any of the releases did this feature was made available directly in the Email templates ?

Thanks!

Comment: As of now, there is no direct way to Capture Prior Value in Email template.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the Email is sent from a trigger that fires on `AfterUpdate` of *that particular field value* OR the prior value is either:

1. stored in the Object History or
2. stored in a custom field on the Object

it's not going to be available when an Email is sent in another context.

Once the database has been overwritten, the previous value would be gone. After the prior value has been overwritten during an update, where would it be obtained from unless stored in another location?